# How to transfer all needed certificates etc to another system

Tags: android, ios, certificate, keystore

I have made an app for both iOS and Android but I am now going to be purchasing a new laptop. What would I need to do to transfer all the necessary files and certificates so that I can carry on working on/updating this app on my new laptop? Also what files would I need to transfer for both Mac OS and Windows for both mobile platform?

Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: What development environment are you using? Your previous laptop os and new os. Which one is mac and which one is windows.

Comment: I have 2, windows for android and mac for iOS but will be switching to only Mac OS